# Как заставить Perl отрабатывать на сервере?

Tags: html, perl, cgi

Всем привет. С перлом пока не знаком, **вообще**.
Есть простейшая html-форма, предварительно валидирующаяся js'ом - не суть. Запрос уходит к файлу testing.cgi (Perl-скрипту), который должен что-нибудь да выполнять (вывести сообщение, например, в окно браузера):

```
#!perl.exe -w
  print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; 

  print "HELLO, WORLD!!!";
```

Однако же в окно браузера **выводится сам листинг**, а не результат работы скрипта.
Работаю с опенсервер, делал всё (+-, есть некоторые расхождения в связи с датой статьи) по этой [статье](http://open-server.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=90)

Ну и да, если кто-то хочет посоветовать какой-то годный источник инфы или сам её вбросить касательно работы связки перл+браузер - буду рад, ибо тут йа чайник =))

Конфигурация сервера (apache-2.2_server.conf): https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Lgg48y5uNaSGtnTGN3X1NBT1k

**UPD!**
так-с, я идиот... я запускал просто сам файлик в адресной строке, а не посредством формы.
при отправке данных формы к этому файлику (через action) я получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

НО если указывать в action расширение **.pl** , то всё работает. по лабе нужен именно cgi-скрипт..

Comment: Приведите полные данные: что именно у вас в конфигах.

Comment: И причем тут "данные с формы" которые у вас в заглавии вопроса. У вас пока проблема же с настройками web-сервера (нет разрешения ExecCGI на папку где лежит скрипт или не прописан обработчик для расширения .cgi ), а не с получением параметров запроса. старайтесь что бы один вопрос здесь был о чем то одном, конкретном.

Comment: кинул ссылку на конфиг в вопросе.

@Mike, понял Вас, извиняюсь)

Comment: что то ссылка не открывается :(

Comment: А по той первой ссылке по которой вы настраивали в принципе все верно. `+ExecCGI` в Options папки где лежит скрипт. `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi` в глобальные настройки. Убеждаемся что cgi в принципе могут быть (подключен mod_cgi или собран внутрь апача). На счет последнего с ресстром не в курсе, под виндой никогда не поднимал. Но по идее если апач попытается запустить скрипт и ему это не удастся будет ошибка 500. А так как у вас выглядит когда апач ничего не знает про cgi и не пытается запускать

Comment: @Mike, странно, у друзей всё открывается... как-то ещё можно скинуть файл?

Comment: дело в том, что у меня нет %htmldir% , как в статье, но есть такое:<Directory "%ssitedir%/*">
    AllowOverride All
    Options -MultiViews +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +IncludesNoExec +Includes +ExecCGI
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: Раз 500 лезет - смотреть апачевские логи в первую очередь. И хорошо бы в начало скрипта добавить строку `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);` (модуль `CGI::Carp` должен быть установлен, если его нет).

Comment: @PinkTux, вот что в "Apache отладка":
[Thu Oct 27 16:32:29 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] D:/OpenServer/domains/localhost/Vlada/Vlada/public_html/testing.cgi is not executable; ensure interpreted scripts have "#!" or "'!" first line, referer: http://localhost/Lab5/lab5.html
[Thu Oct 27 16:32:29 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (9)Bad file descriptor: don't know how to spawn child process: D:/OpenServer/domains/localhost/Vlada/Vlada/public_html/testing.cgi, referer: http://localhost/Lab5/lab5.html

Comment: Попробуйте так: `#!perl -w` (без .exe).

Comment: @PinkTux, да-да, сам прочёл только что лог и решил проблему))

Comment: всем спасибо огромное!

Comment: простите помогу закрыть вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в `#!perl.exe -w`, нужно писать без `.exe`

```
#!perl -w
  print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"; 

  print "HELLO, WORLD!!!";
```

Благодарности: [PinkTux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194908/pinktux)